# WebDriverWait failure to waiting for that URL

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

WebDriverWait failure to waiting for that URL, and the waiting tag information as following :

```
class="iw_component" id="c1417094965155"
```

prompt the error messages `"selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: "` from the following code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

display=Display(visible=0,size=(800,800))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "iw_component"))
)
finally:
    driver.quit()
    display.stop()
```

Comment: First, try increasing the `delay`. Currently you are using only 1 second as the delay. `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`

Comment: dears, actually i'm tried 20, but it seem also not work, thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are after, is located inside a `<iframe>` tag with `id="sysdata_iframe"`. First, you'll have to switch to that frame using [`driver.switch_to.frame()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url")
driver.switch_to.frame('sysdata_iframe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'iw_component')))
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Before doing the switching it's better to define `explicit wait` as well `wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#sysdata_iframe")))`.

Comment: @SIM, yes it can be used as a precaution here. But, the `<iframe id="sysdata_iframe">` is available in the page source and is not loaded dynamically, so the wait is not needed for this frame.